# Use UI elements from static function

Tags: c++, qt, static, static-functions

I am building a qt application in which i am have to access ui elements. but i am getting error as

> invalid use of member 'foo::ui' in static member function

The code is big so cant add here.

Declaration of ui

```
private:
Ui::foo *ui;
```

Initialization in Constructor

```
foo::foo(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::foo)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Accessing in static function where it is giving error.

```
ui->fp->setText("Some Text");
```

Static function declaration.

```
static I eventCallback(PVOID i_pv_context,
        T_xyz i_i_command,
        PVOID i_pv_param);
```

main code

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    BarrierInterfaceModule w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
  }
```

I have looked on Internet but did not get solution. please let me know if there is a way around.let me know if you need any more info Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the error does say it. `ui` is not static so you can't use it without an object in a static method. Why do you need that method to be static and can you make `ui` static also?

Comment: Your error code is straight forward. every *non-static member-function* must be called via an object.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen its a third party function so have it has to be static.

Comment: That's the deal with static functions: they can't access non-static members. Does that function need to be static? If so, consider passing `ui` to it.

Comment: @WhiZTiM i will add in question

Comment: @SergeySlepov The function has to be static and i know we cant access UI but i wanted to know if there is some work around

Comment: Can you pass `ui` into `eventCallback` through `i_pv_context` or `i_pv_param`? They look like they're void pointers so can point to anything.

Comment: @SergeySlepov actually no because it is called by third party function which has specific format. its a callback function as you cam see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware of two possible solutions:

1. Use a [singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) for `foo`. This method only works if you need only one instantiation of `foo`, which is probably the case because it is a `QMainWindow`. Now, you can set the text as follows: `getInstance()->ui->fp->setText("Some Text");`
2. Often callback function are able to pass a pointer to user supplied data, but this depends on the library you are using.

Comment: thanks for the answer i had also come to same conclusion(to use singleton). but my object is created in main as                                          `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    BarrierInterfaceModule w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
    }`

Comment: sorry for bad format of above comment. i don't know how to use singleton in that case.

Comment: Why do you not rewrite it as: `BarrierInterfaceModule::getInstance()->show ();`